# how to get checked value of a checkbox in a shared function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Listed below is the definition of my function (vb).

I am trying to check the value of a checkbox inside the function. I am currently unable to do this without getting an error stating that

> "Error 305: Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class."

Is there anything I can change so that I can get the value to see that if a checkbox is checked or not? The method must be shared, so it works with the existing javascript and the use of pagemethods

Thanks

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function Load(inputs here - taken out for stack overflow) As String
```

edit- the only other solution i can think of is to find a way for the page's javascript onload to run before the server side, this would solve my issue as well if anyone knows how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Do what the message suggests and make the method non-shared, then you'll be able to access the members of the page.

Comment: method must be shared, used with javascript and the use of pagemethods.

Comment: Then you need to pass in an instance of your page or your checkbox, if the method really must be shared.